# Renamed project will not run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash

recently we've taken a project and renamed it and changed class names to generic names to be used as a template for future apps. The problem we're having is now that the project has been renamed it will no longer run. We keep getting errors such as below. Any Help would be great! Thank you!

```
Ld "/Users/mejim707/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTemplate_HD-enipxoysstcfkqevpmxrhtkwglhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppTemplate HD.app/AppTemplate HD" normal i386
cd "/Users/mejim707/Desktop/untitled folder/AppTemplate HD"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/mejim707/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTemplate_HD-enipxoysstcfkqevpmxrhtkwglhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mejim707/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTemplate_HD-enipxoysstcfkqevpmxrhtkwglhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/mejim707/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTemplate_HD-enipxoysstcfkqevpmxrhtkwglhy/Build/Intermediates/AppTemplate HD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppTemplate HD.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppTemplate HD.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -lz.1.2.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework StoreKit -o "/Users/mejim707/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTemplate_HD-enipxoysstcfkqevpmxrhtkwglhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppTemplate HD.app/AppTemplate HD"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppTemplateViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppTemplateAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your build phases, then compile sources to see if there is any classes that are still being called that aren't there. I get that error all the time when I change class names, or remove classes.

Comment: The file named AppTemplateViewController.m needed to be added to compile sources! Now the app builds without issue. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!!

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct. If not, write your own response and include your solution and mark as answered. Sincerely, your friendly neighborhood stack-overflower.